# Automatically open app when receive push notification for FCM (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make the app open automatically when it receive the push notification, i am using Firebase Cloud Messaging and i've already read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368716/how-to-automatically-open-app-when-receive-push-notification) about the same problem but i don't quite understand on how to use it for flutter

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Please any answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to automatically launch the app once a notification has been received from Firebase Cloud Messaging. As mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload), payloads received while the app is in the background can only be handled when the user taps on the notification.